# NameError (uninitialized constant EngageStudent::Engagecourse)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

```
# app/models/engage_course.rb

class EngageCourse < ApplicationRecord

   has_many :engagestudents
end


#app/models/engage_student.rb

class EngageStudent < ApplicationRecord

   belongs_to :engagecourse
end
```

my `schema.rb` is:

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_06_29_093333) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "engage_courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "topic"
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.integer "seats"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "engage_students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "phone"
    t.string "college"
    t.string "semester"
    t.string "status"
    t.bigint "engagecourse_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["engagecourse_id"], name: "index_engage_students_on_engagecourse_id"
  end

end
```

So while creating record for `enagestudent` from **rails console** getting error `NameError (uninitialized constant EngageStudent::Engagecourse)`

I think the model is not able to map other models correctly.
I want to create `engaestudent`  for `engagecouse`.

Please see screenshot.[image]

Comment: As noted, rails has no idea that `engagecourse` is two words and not one. It may be obvious to you, as a human, but not to a machine. And even humans can have troubles: how many words are there in `expertsexchange`? One? Two? _Three_?

Comment: Great example @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, rails will try to look for class `Engagecourse`, and not `EngageCourse`, because of the way you defined [`belongs_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to). You can pass `class_name` to let it know, what class you want to use for this association:

```
class EngageStudent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :engagecourse, class_name: 'EngageCourse'
end
```

**UPDATE**

There is another way of doing this, but that requires a change in your DB schema (keeping rails conventions in mind). Keep your model names as is, and change your associations to their *underscored* versions:

```
class EngageCourse < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :engage_students
end

class EngageStudent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :engage_course
end
```

**Change in DB:** You will have to rename column "engagecourse_id" in table "engage_students" to "engage_course_id".

Comment: This is a valid workaround for a completely unnecessary issue. It is much better to just stick to rails conventions here. There's no reason not to (other than not being aware of the conventions)

Comment: Your comment mentioned the convention but you removed it, in favor of this answer. Add that bit, as it explains the proper fix for the problem.

Comment: My comment required the change in database. So, i removed it. Will add the correct one here.